# Looking for a more efficient way to use multiple input type submit buttons with one ISSET($_POST[submit?]) code

Tags: php, html, form-submit, shortcode, isset

I need a little help with some code. I have html and PHP code that right now uses 13 input type submit buttons. Right now, I will have to duplicate the php isset for submit1 through submit13, even though the code is the same for each. Is there an easier way to use one isset($_POST[submit?]) no matter which of the input type submit buttons is pressed?

```
<?php
session_start();
global $current_user;
(get_currentuserinfo());
$link=mysqli_connect($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);
$_SESSION["user_sex"] = $current_user->gender2;
$abc = "";
    if (isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
    $abc = "show";
    $tdate = $_POST['tdate'];
    $_SESSION["LeagueType_ID"] = (int)$_POST['lgType_id'];
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `wp_tournaments` WHERE `start_tourn` = '$tdate' AND tourn_level_type_id = $_SESSION[LeagueType_ID] ";
    $ressql1 = mysqli_query($link, $sql1) or die("Bad Query: $sql1");
    $_SESSION["MinAge"] = 18;
    $_SESSION["Facility_ID"] = 541;
    $_SESSION["Facility2_ID"] = 1520;
// League Player Dropdown - Men for Women(MX) or Same Sex for Doubles
// Needed for Men's Doubles - Male looking for male partner     
if (($_SESSION["user_sex"] == "Male") and ($_SESSION["LeagueType_ID"] == 3) and ($_SESSION["MinAge"] == 18)) {
        $queryPartner = "SELECT * FROM `wp_players` WHERE wp_players.gender2 = 'Male' AND region_id = 1";
}elseif (($_SESSION["user_sex"] == "Male") and ($_SESSION["LeagueType_ID"] == 3) and ($_SESSION["MinAge"] == 18)) {
    $bd = reverse_birthday($_SESSION["MinAge"]);
    $queryPartner = "SELECT * FROM `wp_players` WHERE wp_players.gender2 = 'Male' AND region_id = 1 AND birth_date < '$bd'";
}
// Needed for Mixed - Male looking for Female partner
if (($_SESSION["user_sex"] == "Male") and ($_SESSION["LeagueType_ID"] == 5) and ($_SESSION["MinAge"] == 18)) {
        $queryPartner = "SELECT * FROM `wp_players` WHERE wp_players.gender2 = 'Female' AND region_id = 1";
}elseif (($_SESSION["user_sex"] == "Male") and ($_SESSION["LeagueType_ID"] == 5) and ($_SESSION["MinAge"] == 18)) {
    $bd = reverse_birthday($_SESSION["MinAge"]);
    $queryPartner = "SELECT * FROM `wp_players` WHERE wp_players.gender2 = 'Female' AND region_id = 1 AND birth_date < '$bd'";
}
// Needed for Women's Doubles - Female looking for Female partner
if (($_SESSION["user_sex"] == "Female") and ($_SESSION["LeagueType_ID"] == 4) and ($_SESSION["MinAge"] == 18)) {
        $queryPartner = "SELECT * FROM `wp_players` WHERE wp_players.gender2 = 'Female' AND region_id = 1";
}elseif (($_SESSION["user_sex"] == "Female") and ($_SESSION["LeagueType_ID"] == 4) and ($_SESSION["MinAge"] == 18)) {
    $bd = reverse_birthday($_SESSION["MinAge"]);
    $queryPartner = "SELECT * FROM `wp_players` WHERE wp_players.gender2 = 'Female' AND region_id = 1 AND birth_date < '$bd'";
}
// Needed for Mixed Doubles - Female looking for Male partner
if (($_SESSION["user_sex"] == "Female") and ($_SESSION["LeagueType_ID"] == 5)) {
        $queryPartner = "SELECT * FROM `wp_players` WHERE wp_players.gender2 = 'Male' AND region_id = 1";
}elseif (($_SESSION["user_sex"] == "Female") and ($_SESSION["LeagueType_ID"] == 5) and ($_SESSION["MinAge"] == 18)) {
    $bd = reverse_birthday($_SESSION["MinAge"]);
    $queryPartner = "SELECT * FROM `wp_players` WHERE wp_players.gender2 = 'Male' AND region_id = 1 AND birth_date < '$bd'";
}
$resultDbls = mysqli_query($link, $queryPartner);
// End of Tournament Player Dropdown - Men for Women(MX)            
}
    if (isset($_POST['submit2']))
{
    $abc = "show";
    $tdate = $_POST['tdate'];
    $_SESSION["LeagueType_ID"] = (int)$_POST['lgType_id'];
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `wp_tournaments` WHERE `start_tourn` = '$tdate' AND tourn_level_type_id = $_SESSION[LeagueType_ID] ";
    $ressql1 = mysqli_query($link, $sql1) or die("Bad Query: $sql1");
    $_SESSION["MinAge"] = 18;
    $_SESSION["Facility_ID"] = 541;
    $_SESSION["Facility2_ID"] = 1520;
// League Player Dropdown - Men for Women(MX) or Same Sex for Doubles
// Needed for Men's Doubles - Male looking for male partner     
if (($_SESSION["user_sex"] == "Male") and ($_SESSION["LeagueType_ID"] == 3) and ($_SESSION["MinAge"] == 18)) {
        $queryPartner = "SELECT * FROM `wp_players` WHERE wp_players.gender2 = 'Male' AND region_id = 1";
}elseif (($_SESSION["user_sex"] == "Male") and ($_SESSION["LeagueType_ID"] == 3) and ($_SESSION["MinAge"] == 18)) {
    $bd = reverse_birthday($_SESSION["MinAge"]);
    $queryPartner = "SELECT * FROM `wp_players` WHERE wp_players.gender2 = 'Male' AND region_id = 1 AND birth_date < '$bd'";
}
// Needed for Mixed - Male looking for Female partner
if (($_SESSION["user_sex"] == "Male") and ($_SESSION["LeagueType_ID"] == 5) and ($_SESSION["MinAge"] == 18)) {
        $queryPartner = "SELECT * FROM `wp_players` WHERE wp_players.gender2 = 'Female' AND region_id = 1";
}elseif (($_SESSION["user_sex"] == "Male") and ($_SESSION["LeagueType_ID"] == 5) and ($_SESSION["MinAge"] == 18)) {
    $bd = reverse_birthday($_SESSION["MinAge"]);
    $queryPartner = "SELECT * FROM `wp_players` WHERE wp_players.gender2 = 'Female' AND region_id = 1 AND birth_date < '$bd'";
}
// Needed for Women's Doubles - Female looking for Female partner
if (($_SESSION["user_sex"] == "Female") and ($_SESSION["LeagueType_ID"] == 4) and ($_SESSION["MinAge"] == 18)) {
        $queryPartner = "SELECT * FROM `wp_players` WHERE wp_players.gender2 = 'Female' AND region_id = 1";
}elseif (($_SESSION["user_sex"] == "Female") and ($_SESSION["LeagueType_ID"] == 4) and ($_SESSION["MinAge"] == 18)) {
    $bd = reverse_birthday($_SESSION["MinAge"]);
    $queryPartner = "SELECT * FROM `wp_players` WHERE wp_players.gender2 = 'Female' AND region_id = 1 AND birth_date < '$bd'";
}
// Needed for Mixed Doubles - Female looking for Male partner
if (($_SESSION["user_sex"] == "Female") and ($_SESSION["LeagueType_ID"] == 5)) {
        $queryPartner = "SELECT * FROM `wp_players` WHERE wp_players.gender2 = 'Male' AND region_id = 1";
}elseif (($_SESSION["user_sex"] == "Female") and ($_SESSION["LeagueType_ID"] == 5) and ($_SESSION["MinAge"] == 18)) {
    $bd = reverse_birthday($_SESSION["MinAge"]);
    $queryPartner = "SELECT * FROM `wp_players` WHERE wp_players.gender2 = 'Male' AND region_id = 1 AND birth_date < '$bd'";
}
$resultDbls = mysqli_query($link, $queryPartner);
// End of Tournament Player Dropdown - Men for Women(MX)            
}
$def = "";      
if (isset($_POST['submitform1']))
{
    $def = "show";
}
$ghi = "";
if (isset($_POST['submitpaypal']))
{
    $ghi = "show";
}
?>
<html>
        <style type="text/css">
        #box1 {
            border: ridge;
            color: black;
        }
        #box2 {
            border: ridge;
            color: black;
        }
        p {
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
        div {
            line-height: normal;
        }
    </style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
<div id="Front">
<div id = "box1">
    <form method="POST">
    <p>
        <b>Adult Mixed Doubles Tournament</b><br/>
        <br/>
        <b>Adult Doubles Tournament - Men's/Women's</b><br/>
        <br/>
        <b>Dates:</b> April<br/>
        <b>NTRP Levels:</b> 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0 <br/>
        <br/>
        <b>Location:</b>Tennis Center - (555) 528-2626<br/>
        <b>Address:</b>  <br/>
        <br/>
        <b>Location:</b> Tennis Center - (555) 454-3777<br/>
        <b>Address:</b><br/>
        <br/>
        <input type='hidden' name='lgType_id' value=5>
        <input type='hidden' name='tdate' value='2020-02-27'>
        <input type="submit" value="Register to Play" name="submit1">
    </p>
    </form>
</div>  
<div id="box1">
    <form method="POST">
    <p>
        <b>Adult Singles Tournament - Men's/Women's</b><br/>
        <br/>
        <b>Adult Doubles Tournament - Men's/Women's</b><br/>
        <br/>
        <b>Dates:</b> April<br/>
        <b>NTRP Levels:</b> 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0 <br/>
        <br/>
        <b>Location:</b>Tennis Center - (555) 528-2626<br/>
        <b>Address:</b>  <br/>
        <br/>
        <b>Location:</b> Tennis Center - (555) 454-3777<br/>
        <b>Address:</b><br/>
        <?php if ($_SESSION["user_sex"] =='Male') { ?>
        <input type='hidden' name='lgType_id' value=1>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($_SESSION["user_sex"] =='Female') { ?>
        <input type='hidden' name='lgType_id' value=2>
        <?php } ?>
        <input type='hidden' name='tdate' value='2020-03-05'>
        <input type="submit" value="Register to Play" name="submit2">
    </p>
    </form>
</div>      
<div id="box1">
    <form method="POST">
    <p>
        <b>Adult Doubles Tournament - Men's/Women's</b><br/>
        <br/>
        <b>Dates:</b> April<br/>
        <b>NTRP Levels:</b> 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0 <br/>
        <br/>
        <b>Location:</b>Tennis Center - (555) 528-2626<br/>
        <b>Address:</b>  <br/>
        <br/>
        <b>Location:</b> Tennis Center - (555) 454-3777<br/>
        <b>Address:</b><br/>
        <?php if ($_SESSION["user_sex"] =='Male') { ?>
        <input type='hidden' name='lgType_id' value=3>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($_SESSION["user_sex"] =='Female') { ?>
        <input type='hidden' name='lgType_id' value=4>
        <?php } ?>
        <input type='hidden' name='tdate' value='2020-04-02'>
        <input type="submit" value="Register to Play" name="submit3">
    </p>
    </form>
</div>
</div>  
<div id="firstForm1">
<form method='POST'>
    <h4>Adult Tournament <?php echo $tdate; echo $lgType_id; ?></h4>
<br>
    <select class="chosen" name="formtournlvl" id="TournLevel" required>
            <option value="">Select Your Tournament Level....</option>
        <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ressql1)):;?>
        <option value=<?php echo $row1['ID'];?>><?php echo $row1['description'];?></option>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    </select>
<br><br>
    <select class="chosen" name="DblsPartner" id="selectPartner" >
        <option value="">Doubles Partner Selection:</option>
        <option value=0>**** Partner not Listed ****</option>
        <?php
            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultDbls)):;?>
        <option value=<?php echo $row1['id'];?>><?php echo $row1['display_name'] . " - " . $row1['user_city'] . ", " . $row1['user_state'] . ", " . $row1['user_zip'] . "";?></option>
            <?php 
            endwhile;
            ?>
    </select>   
<br><br>
    <input class="pull-right" type="submit" name="submitform1" value="Move to Step 2" required>
</form>
</div>
<div id="secondForm1">
<form method='POST'>
    <h4>Page 2</h4>
    <input type="submit" class="pull-right" name="submitpaypal" value="Next Step" style="margin-left:10px;">
</form>
</div>
<div id="thirdForm1">
    <h4>Page 3</h4>
</div>
<?php
if($abc!=""){
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#Front").hide();
$("#firstForm1").show();
$("#secondForm1").hide();
$("#thirdForm1").hide();
     </script>
<?php
}elseif($def!=""){
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#Front").hide();
$("#firstForm1").hide();
$("#secondForm1").show();
$("#thirdForm1").hide();
     </script>
    <?php
}elseif($ghi!=""){
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#Front").hide();
$("#firstForm1").hide();
$("#secondForm1").hide();
$("#thirdForm1").show();
</script>
<?php
}else{
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#Front").show();
$("#firstForm1").hide();
$("#secondForm1").hide();
$("#thirdForm1").hide();
</script>
<?php
}
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(".chosen").chosen();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have read through a number of questions previously submitted and was not able to find one that was similar to what I was asking. A number of answers submitted on other questions helped me get this far.

I like the format of having all of the input type submit buttons, but would like to only have one isset($_POST[submit?] php code.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try like this for all submit button**

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
  {
      // access all your form data here
  }
```